# Font size increase in RTL Arabic view

Tags: angular, sass, font-size, direction, scss-functions

I have situation where i want to increase arabic fontsize by 4px only on RTL.

the first solution is increase the root font-size on rtl

```
ex:
html{
  font-size: 20px
}

html[dir="rtl"]{
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

but here the sideeffect with above approch,
the font-size will increase every where but other css proerty size also increase whichever using rem unit,
but i want only fontsize to increased.

I have complex app with 300 components,  need a solution which takes fewer file changes.

for your information its a **Angular 12 with scss** app

tech stack: Angular 12, scss

Thank you in advance

tried scss function but did'nt get way to identify the direction to appy in if condition

```
$direction: 'ltr';

html[dir= 'rtl']{
  $direction: 'rtl' !global;
}

@function adjustFontSize($fontsize) {
  @if ($direction == "rtl") {
    @return calc(#{$fontsize} + 4px);
  }
  @return $fontsize;
}

.home {
  font-size: adjustFontSize(1rem);
}
```